# Select all rows that dont match a date format?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am attempting to migrate/update an old table that allowed a nullable varchar in a supposed "date" field. I want to find all rows that don't match this format: **`%e-%b-%y`**. How can I accomplish this query?

**EDIT: I should mention that the field does contain a few "CANCELLED", null, or other string values instead of the more common e-b-y format. I am looking for those rows so I can update them to the format I want (%e-%b-%y).

Comment: How about casting them to `DATE`, then converting it to that format, and checking to see if they match.  eg. `SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE DATE_FORMAT(CAST(date_field, DATE), '%e-%b-%y') <> date_field`

Comment: You can also use [`STR_TO_DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)

Comment: Why on earth has someone down voted this?  Cannot see any justifiable reason.

Comment: The problem is, that when I try to do a STR_TO_DATE() the field may contain values such as "Cancelled", NULL, or a different date format.

Comment: Yes, but that's why you do the reverse conversion as I said, to pick up where it has worked from where it has not.

Comment: @Orbling: The suggestion from your initial comment sounds very reasonable, do you care to make that an answer so I can upvote it?

Comment: @MvG: No time to flesh it out - feel free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more approach is to try to recover as much dates as possible with different formats using `STR_TO_DATE()` which will return `NULL` if extracted value is invalid and `COALESCE()` to chain different date formats.

To show only rows with unrecoverable dates:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table1
 WHERE COALESCE(STR_TO_DATE(NULLIF(dt, ''), '%e-%b-%Y'),
                STR_TO_DATE(NULLIF(dt, ''), '%e-%b-%y'),
                STR_TO_DATE(NULLIF(dt, ''), '%Y-%m-%d'),
                STR_TO_DATE(NULLIF(dt, ''), '%m/%d/%Y'),
                STR_TO_DATE(NULLIF(dt, ''), '%m/%d/%y')) IS NULL;
```

To see what will you have got after converting dates:

```
SELECT *, COALESCE(STR_TO_DATE(NULLIF(dt, ''), '%e-%b-%Y'),
                   STR_TO_DATE(NULLIF(dt, ''), '%e-%b-%y'),
                   STR_TO_DATE(NULLIF(dt, ''), '%Y-%m-%d'),
                   STR_TO_DATE(NULLIF(dt, ''), '%m/%d/%Y'),
                   STR_TO_DATE(NULLIF(dt, ''), '%m/%d/%y')) new_date
  FROM table1;
```

**Note:**

- You can chain as much format strings as you need.
- Use four digit formats `%y` before two digits `%y`. Otherwise you'll get incorrect dates.

If you were to have following sample data:

```
| ID |          DT |
|----|-------------|
|  1 |   CANCELLED |
|  2 |   02-Mar-12 |
|  3 |      (null) |
|  4 |    5-Aug-13 |
|  5 |             |
|  6 |  2013-09-12 |
|  7 |  10/23/2013 |
|  8 | 13-Aug-2012 |
```

Then the second query produces following output:

```
| ID |          DT |                         NEW_DATE |
|----|-------------|----------------------------------|
|  1 |   CANCELLED |                           (null) |
|  2 |   02-Mar-12 |     March, 02 2012 00:00:00+0000 |
|  3 |      (null) |                           (null) |
|  4 |    5-Aug-13 |    August, 05 2013 00:00:00+0000 |
|  5 |             |                           (null) |
|  6 |  2013-09-12 | September, 12 2013 00:00:00+0000 |
|  7 |  10/23/2013 |   October, 23 2013 00:00:00+0000 |
|  8 | 13-Aug-2012 |    August, 13 2012 00:00:00+0000 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/36c6d/1)** demo

Comment: A combined answer from you and @Orbling both helped me out! Thank you for this!

Comment: @peterm There is a typo in your answer. There seems to be too many pending Edits, otherwise I would have recommended there. 

> Use four digit formats %y before two digits %y.

The latter should be "before two digits `%Y`".

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions in MySQL; see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_not-regexp

Here's an expression that returns rows where the date field (dt) is null or does not match 1-2 digits + dash + 3 alphabetic characters + dash + 2 digits (for example, 06-Sep-13)

```
select * from table_name where dt is null or 
  dt not rlike '[[:digit:]]{1,2}-[[:alpha:]]{3}-[[:digit:]]{2}';
```

Answer (score 1):

This is based on the [comment by Orbling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18665860/mysql-select-all-rows-that-dont-match-a-date-format?noredirect=1#comment27489739_18665860). You can do the following:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(CAST(date_field, DATE), '%e-%b-%y') <> date_field
```

What this does is it takes the date_field, tries to convert that to a date, and then converts that date back to a string, which is compared against the original string. If the two don't match, then the line is reported. If conversions fail, your MySQL client might report a warning, but you can safely ignore those.

This is a *very* strict check: it will report any line where you could not recreate *exactly* the original situation by formatting the date accordingly. In particular, this will complain about differences in leading zeros, trailing whitespace, and so on. If that is a problem, you can either find a less strict check (perhaps based on a date validity check combined with some regular expression), or do some simple pattern matching to identify and correct these rows so that they match the desired format. Like finding all lines matching `__-_-____` and introducing a `0` after the first dash.

Comment: Thank you for this! Combined with above, helped me work out the fields I needed to find. Also, I couldn't get it to work doing Cast(date_field, Date). I had to use Case(date_field AS Date).